# Compilation differences between iOS target 5 and iOS target 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

My iOS App was written with the iOS 5 SDK. the iOS target version of 5 was never modified when I switched to newer version of the SDKs as required by apple.
with the new SDK (9) I can't get it to compile with the old setting and i'm attempting to switch over to a newer target. (6,7,8,9, I get the same issues). the app has mixed code, some files use ARC and some don't. when i switch to newer OS target I get many errors regarding ARC, mostly around dispatch queue management (dispatch_retain/dispatch_release). if i add the -fno-objc-arc the app crashes, if i remove the dispatch_retain/release calls the app crashes. my questions are:

1. **Does anyone knows what was changed in the SDK compilation regrading ARC between iOS 5 and 6?**
2. **Any recommendations how to move forward? is there a way to keep arc enabled but tell the compiler to allow manual handling of the dispatch queues?**

Answer (score 0):

1. Nothing significant.
2. You have to manage queues manually anyway. The only way that ARC interacts with dispatch_* is when you use a block. It's likely that this has always been a problem and that optimisations in the new compiler expose it.

Without seeing the code it's difficult to make any specific recommendations. In general, I tend to set up a queue when the app launches and never deallocate it. trying to find the right times to retain/release a queue just feels like a problem that I don't need to deal with.